# Java Datetime format parsed in C#

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I've been told I'm going to receive a datetime in the format:

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:sss
```

That comes from a Java web service, even if I'm trying to get what's the point for the three "sss" at the end it seems to be the final format and not a typo.

So I'm trying to Parse it using .Net (actually C#)

```
var s = "2014-09-16T12:17:057";
var d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it raises an exception

Sting was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Thanks,

UPDATE:

As suspected, third time the charm and I've been confirmed the actual format should be

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
```

Comment: What web service are you trying to reach? They probably explain how to use it somewhere.

Comment: @mitomed, lower case `ss` is for seconds but it is limited to two digits, Upper case `SSS` is for milliseconds. So make sure your format, that you have been told,  is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [Java date format documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html), I believe you will be receiving `000` through `059` in the seconds part of your string. Also Java doesn't seem to be *capable* of supplying a tenth of a second.

> The number of symbol letters you specify also determines the format.
>
> Number | minimum number of digits is required | shorter numbers are padded with zeros

Thus parsing it as `ssf` will result in the seconds part of the time being divided by 10.

If this is the case, then the C# format string you need to use is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:0ss`.

That said, your "Java format string" contains `mm` for both month and minute and `hh` for hours (12-hour) with no indication of an AM/PM specifier, so who knows how reliable it is?

Comment: You're right. This is a mess. I  will insist on the third party that sent me this (even if I have confirmed that point twice) that there's no typo in it.

Comment: @Rawling, one issue though in your linked document there is: "H:mm:ss:SSS 8:28:36:249" , so the seconds value is not exactly between `000 to 059`. `SSS` is for milliseconds, may be upper case lower case difference for seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: @Habib I don't follow. Multiple `s` is seconds, multiple `S` is milliseconds. More `s` or `S` than required gives leading zeroes. Hence in your example `ss` gives `36`, `SSS` gives `249`; `sss` would give `036`.

Comment: @Rawling, "More s or S than required gives leading zeroes" - That is what I missed. You are absolutely right. +1